# Jquery effect disappear after .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this script to add some effect on my content ( flip effect, and tab)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('#flip-container').quickFlip();

        $('#flip-navigation li a').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                $('#flip-navigation li').each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                });
                $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
                var flipid = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
                $('#flip-container').quickFlipper({}, flipid, 1);

                return false;
            });
        });
    });
```

However after a .load (to load the page), the effect disappear, and all content of my tabs are displayed.

Here is the code I use for loading content :

```
 $(function () {

if (Modernizr.history) {

    var newHash = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function () {
        _link = $(this).attr("href");
        history.pushState(null, null, _link);
        loadContent(_link);
        return false;
    });

    function loadContent(href) {
        $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function () {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", function () {



                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function () {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        console.log(href);
                        $("nav a[href$=" + href + "]").addClass("current");



                    });
                });
    }

    $(window).bind('popstate', function () {
        _link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); //get filename only
        loadContent(_link);
    });

} // otherwise, history is not supported, so nothing fancy here.


});
```

Is there a way to not negate them ? Some topics used the on() function, but I don't really know how to use it here. If possible I would like it to work without having to click somewhere beforehand.

[Here](http://exerion.comule.com/Default.html) is the link to the site. Only the page Acceuil and Semaine Prochaine work. The quickflip is used on the second one.
On Acceuil there should be some effect as well ( like [here](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tablecloth/) ) but the effect only work on the first load.

Here is the updated solution:

```
 function loadContent(href) {
        $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function () {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", function () {
                        $.getScript('js/jquery.quickflip.min.js', function () {

                            $('#flip-container').quickFlip();

                            $('#flip-navigation li a').each(function () {
                                $(this).click(function () {
                                    $('#flip-navigation li').each(function () {
                                        $(this).removeClass('selected');
                                    });
                                    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
                                    var flipid = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
                                    $('#flip-container').quickFlipper({}, flipid, 1);

                                    return false;
                                });
                            });

                        });

                        $.getScript('tablecloth/tablecloth.js', function () {
                            tablecloth();
                        });

                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function () {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        console.log(href);
                        $("nav a[href$=" + href + "]").addClass("current");



                    });
                });
    }
```

Comment: are you dynamically adding content to your page through javascript ? Is it what you mean with your "load" sentence ? You would need delegated events for those dynamically added items then...

Comment: Which element(s) are you using `.load()` on?

Comment: P.S. As an aside, you don't need either of those `.each()` loops. You can just say `$('#flip-navigation li a').click(...` and `$('#flip-navigation li').removeClass('selected');`

Comment: Sorry I forgot the link to the site, please see the updated post. I am using load to change page dynamically.

Comment: .on() is for events not plugin, you need to reinitialize plugin on new added elements. For that, use the load callback function. BTW, post relevant code where you are using load() method

Comment: You got an error on your site: `nav a[href$=Default.html]` should be `nav a[href$='Default.html']` or `nav a[href$="Default.html"]` depending quotes used for selector string

Comment: Weird I always have     <a href="Default.html">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the code in the function executing the `load` instead of in document.ready:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {

    $('#flip-container').quickFlip();

        $('#flip-navigation li a').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                $('#flip-navigation li').each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                });
                $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
                var flipid = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
                $('#flip-container').quickFlipper({}, flipid, 1);

                return false;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Obviously, the line `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function()` needs amending to match your call of `load`.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

The reason for this is that `#flip-container` doesn't exist when you are trying to attach `quickFlip`.  You have to call `$('#flip-container').quickFlip();` after the call to `load` has completed and retrieved the HTML you would like to use `quickFlip` on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I put it just after the ligne `$mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", function () {` It works only if I load first the page Semaine Prochaine, but if I first load Acceuil, then the second one won't even show up.

Comment: I found the solution, I had to add this : `$.getScript('js/jquery.quickflip.min.js', function () {`

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try This code ...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#flip-container').quickFlip();

    $('#flip-navigation li a').each(function () {
        $(this).on("click",function () {
            $('#flip-navigation li').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            });
            $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
            var flipid = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
            $('#flip-container').quickFlipper({}, flipid, 1);

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

I have change `click` event to `on` if you are adding something dynamically it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still has the same behaviour.

Comment: Could you share your HTML or try to give JS Fiddle demo .

Comment: You can find the source [here](http://exerion.comule.com/), as for JS Fiddle, I can't make it work for some reason.